# $i^{1/n}$ when $n \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

What would happen when $n \to \infty$ for $i^{1/n}$. Would it still be an imaginary number or would it simply be $i^0=1$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: **Hint:** Consider writing $i^{\frac 1n}$ as $r\angle \theta$. Squaring doubles the angle thus taking successive roots should halve the angle while $r$ remains constant. What does $\theta$ approach when it is halved infinitely many times?

Comment: Your first problem is to define $i^{1/n}$. Indeed, what is $i^{1/2}$?

Comment: Nitpick:  $i^{\frac 12} =\pm(\frac{\sqrt{2}2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}2} i)$ is *not* an "imaginary number.  It is a complex number.  And $1$ is also a complex number.  An "imaginary" number is in the form $0 + bi$ and there is no reason to assume $i^{\frac 1n}$ will be in this form (and, indeed, if $n > 1$ it will *NOT* be).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set of $n$th roots of $i$ become equidistributed around the unit circle as $n \to \infty$, and so on the face of it this is a delicate question.

It seems to me that the entire crux of this matter comes down to defining what you mean by $i^{1/n}$. You see, this isn't single-valued for complex numbers. Indeed, for any fixed $n$, we might define
$$a^{1/n} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\log a} = e^{\frac{1}{n}(\log \lvert a \rvert + 2\pi i k \arg(a))}$$
for any value of $k$ (although in practice, it's sufficient to choose $0 \leq k < n$). *A priori*, for each $n$th root, one can take a different $k$ and use that branch of the logarithm.

Some of the other answers seem to be assuming that you are defining the $n$th root of $i$ in a way that fixes $k$, and takes that sequence of branches of the log. But this is neither obvious nor necessarily true. **If you fix $k$**, then the limit is $1$. If you choose to let $k \approx n/2$ as $n \to \infty$, then the limit will be $-1$. One might say that this is an odd choice of $k$, but I think it highlights that the choice of $k$ (or rather, exactly how one defines the $n$th root) matters significantly.

Comment: I guess you beat me to it on this one.

Comment: I am glad that you wrote this reply, so I don't have to. I was very unhappy with many of the other replies. It was suggested that every solution $k/n$ goes to zero when you increase $n$. While that is true, new solutions keep popping up around $2\pi$. So the "convergence" to zero is an illusion. Solutions remain equally spaced on the unit circle. In that sense, the answer to the OP's question  must be: the function is multivalued, hence the limit is undefined.

Comment: If someone wants a unique answer, then a Principal Branch must be chosen.

Comment: Thanks for that contribution, now I can also see better the point raised by @M.Wind and I think that your observation are completely correct. The answer deserve some more discussion than a simple hint!

Answer (score 6):

As noticed and discussed in detail by davidlowryduda and Lubin, the existence of the limit depends upon the definition we assume for $i^\frac1n=\sqrt[n] i$.

Notably, according to the standard definition, we have

$$i=e^{i\frac{\pi}2+2ik\pi}\implies \sqrt[n] i=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2n}+i\frac{2k\pi}n} \quad k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$$

which is a multivalued function and therefore we can't define/determine the existence or a value for the limit without defining a "rule" to choose one of the $n$ root.

For example if we assign to $\sqrt[n] i$ the root corresponding to a fixed value for $k=\bar k$ of course the limit is $1$, indeed

$$e^{i\frac{\pi}{2n}+i\frac{2\bar k\pi}n} \to e^0=1$$

but if we choose a value of $k$ depending upon $n$ the limit might be different and assume any value $e^{i\theta}$ for complex number on the unit circle.

Comment: Why this downvote ??

Comment: Let me know if you can guess that! :)

Comment: I am not the down-voter but I recall that the answer was down-voted before the edit that added $2ik\pi$

Comment: Someone downvoted all the answers some time ago...why? Go guess why...

Comment: @Raptor The downvote was given after the editing and for all answers therefore I suppose it is not related to that correction.

Comment: The HINT is good. Now the question is how to interpret the right hand side.

Comment: @M.Wind iIt works in that way: we choose any representation for $i$ that is we fix $k$, then we take the limit. In other words k is not a variable going to infinity it is a value to be fixed before we take the limit.

Answer (score 3):

Write

$$i=e^{\frac\pi2i+2k\pi i}\implies i^\frac1n=e^{\frac\pi{2n}i+\frac{2k\pi i}n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e^0=1$$

So even the number's argument is not uniquely defined, the limit still is one (here we assume the exponential function's continuous on the complex plane. Not so big an assumption...)

Comment: there is no need for the $+2k\pi$ part i guess.

Comment: On the contrary, @hamzaboulahia, would it not make equally good sense to use a different $k$ for each approximating $n$-th root of $i$?

Comment: Indeed it is important, I forgot that!

Comment: As you correctly point out the phase of $i$ is equal to $(1/2 + 2k)\pi$, where k can be $0, 1, 2, 3, 4.....$. If you divide $k$ by $n$ and take the limit of $n$ to infinity, you claim that the result is $0$. I am not sure. One could also argue that for every value of $n$, there are $k$ values which are of the same order or larger. Steadily increasing $n$ does not change this picture. If you look at it from this perspective, the ratio $k/n$ is undefined.

Comment: @M.Wind The game is: you fix k, I choose n.

Comment: Or in other words the $k$ although undetermined is not variable.  $\frac kn \to 0$ for all $k$ so even though $\frac kn$ is not defined or rather is a class of $\{....., \frac {-3}n, \frac {-2n}, -\frac 1n, 0 , \frac 1n, \frac 2n, \frac 3n,.....\}$ the limit is .. $0$.

Comment: If $n $ is a natural number, there are $n$ solutions which are evenly distrubuted over the unit circle. Taking the limit of $n$ to infinity does not change this. Of course the principal value goes to zero, but the complex root is multi-valued.

Comment: @DonAntonio I've just revised my answer according to the good discussion by davidlowryduda and Lubin. I think that their perspective is  a more complete and correct way to answer!

Answer (score 3):

I want to respond to this provocative question as an algebraist, not an analyst. As many have noted, there are $n$ distinct roots of the equation $X^n=i$, equally spaced around the unit circle. And algebra refuses to distinguish among them: any $n$-th root of $i$ will be as good as any other.

If you’re willing to go along with me in this refusal, then you must agree that *every* complex number $a+bi$ on the unit circle, i.e. satisfying $a^2+b^2=1$, is a limit, as $n\to\infty$, of $n$-th roots of $i$, as long as those roots are  properly chosen.

For, let $a+bi$ be such a point on the unit circle. Among the $n$ numbers $\zeta$ satisfying $\zeta^n=i$, there is one, call it $\zeta_n$, that is at a distance of at most $\pi/n$ from $a+bi$. So if we ask for $\lim_n\zeta_n$, the value in answer is our $a+bi$.

( But at least there *are* limits. In my preferred environment, the $p$-adic, any sequence of $n$-th roots of $i$ will have no limit at all. )

Comment: Good point! I was looking the things from a limited point of view.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$ i^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(i)}$$

Now, $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}i^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(i)}=e^0=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be talking about "imaginary" numbers (you actually mean "complex") and "real" numbers as if they are fundamentally different; that all numbers are always one or the other; and that that the is a giant quantuum jump that a "real" number an imaginary number.

Your question seems to be that as $i^{\frac 1n}$ are all one type of number (you said "imaginary" but you seem to mean "non-real complex") and $i^0  = 1$ is the utterly different and incompatible type "real", when what type is $\lim i^{\frac 1n}$?

Well... you have misconceptions.  *All* numbers are complex and lie on the complex plane.  Numbers that lie exactly on the real axis are "real" numbers and numbers that lie exactly on the imaginary axis are "imaginary" numbers.  (Fun trivia fact!  Zero is the only number that is both real and imaginary!)  All other numbers are neither real nor imaginary bout are just "generic" plain old boring complex numbers.

Now there is nothing earth shaking or shattering about lying on either the imaginary axis or the real axis and the real numbers and the imaginary numbers aren't really any different from their nearby numbers that can be very close to the axis.

Now, limits are about "getting close" so something.  And there's nothing mindblowing or quantuum state altering about a bunch of numbers that "get close" to the real axis but aren't themselves on it.

So $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}i^{\frac 1n} = 1 \in \mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$ while each $i^{\frac 1n}\not \in \mathbb R$ (but close  to it) is not a weird or surprising result.

==== tl;dr =====

Your question seems to be confusing "imaginary" number with "complex" number and "complex number" with "non-real complex number".

A "complex" number is of the form $a + bi$ where $a$ and $b$ are real.  If $a = 0$ then we get $0 + bi = bi$ and that is called an "imaginary" or "purely" imaginary number.  It is a *type* of complex number.

If $b = 0$ then $a+0i = a$ and that is .... a real number.  A real number is a type of complex number.  It is not correct to differentiate between complex and real numbers as real numbers are a subset of complex numbers and *everything* you know (so far) as "numbers" are *all* complex numbers.

So if $b \ne 0$ so $a + bi$ is *not* real then we call that a "non real" complex number.

If we define $w^{\frac 1n}$ as the $z$ so that $z^n =w$ there will be $n$ possible values for $z$, Example $i^4, (-i)^4, 1^4, $ and $(-1)^4$ all equal $1$.  So which one is $1^{\frac 14}$?

Or $(\frac {\sqrt 2}2 + \frac {\sqrt 2} 2i)^2 = i$ and $(-\frac {\sqrt 2}2 - \frac {\sqrt 2} 2i)^2$ so which is $i^{\frac 12}$? And for  $z_1= \frac {\sqrt 3}2+ \frac 12  i; z_2 = -\frac {\sqrt{3}}2 + \frac 12 i; z_3 = -i$ then $z_1^3 = z_2^3 = z_3^3 = i$ so which one is $i^{\frac 13}$.

I'm not actually sure that there is an agreed upon answer to this. But one way of thinking of this is to note all of them lie on a circle equi-angles apart. so we can take $w^{\frac 1n}$ to be first from the real axis in the counter clockwise direction.

Another way of putting the is that for every $z = a + bi \ne 0$ there is an angle $\theta$ and a positive real distance $r$ so that $a + bi = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$.  (If we are curious $r = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan \frac ba + k*\pi$ so that $r\sin \theta =b; r\cos \theta = a$)

Using this notation and then $w = a + bi = r*\cos \theta + r*\sin \theta i$ then $w^{\frac 1n} = \sqrt[n]{r}(\cos \frac {\theta}n + i\sin \frac{\theta}n)$.

And so $i^{\frac 1n} = \cos(\frac {90^{\circ}}{n}) + i\sin (\frac {90^{\circ}}n)=\cos (\frac {\pi}{2n}) + i\sin (\frac {\pi}{2n})$

which for $n > 1$ is neither "purely imaginary" nor "real".

But it doesn't take much work to see

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}i^{\frac 1n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cos (\frac {\pi}{2n}) + i\sin (\frac {\pi}{2n}) = \cos (\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac {\pi}{2n}) + i\sin (\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac {\pi}{2n})=\cos 0 + i\sin 0= 1 + 0i = 1$

which is real.

...... ADDENDUM .....

Hmmm.... I think I did a disservice.

Conventionally $w^{\frac 1n}$ is defined to be "multivalued" where it can be *any* of the $n$ possible values.

When converting to "polar notation" $(\theta, r)$ because $w = r(\cos (\theta + 2k\pi) + i\sin (\theta + 2k\pi)) $ for all integers $k$ we can define $w^{\frac 1n} = $ the set of then $n$ different $\sqrt[n]{r}(\cos (\frac \theta a + \frac {2k\pi}n) + i \sin (\frac \theta a + \frac {2k\pi}n))$.

It still follows the even if we chose different values for $k$ that

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{r}(\cos (\frac \theta a + \frac {2k\pi}n) + i \sin (\frac \theta a + \frac {2k\pi}n)) =1$.

I don't have time to fix my post today but I may fix it by Monday.

Comment: We have a function $f(n)$ which is multi-valued. It has $n$ solutions. Increase $n$ and the number of solutions increases. You claim that in the limit of $n$ to infinity all solutions "collapse" into a single solution. That is illogical.

Comment: mmm.... perhaps.  We have to define what the concept of a limit means anyway.  Which for multivalued functions might not make any sense.  We have to ask the OP where the question comes from.  Anyway I don't have time to discuss this now.