# Show that $\sqrt{10}+\sqrt 7>\sqrt{17}$

Tags: inequality

I'm not actually sure what is there to show. It is obvious and can be verified with a calculator.

Is there a formal way of proving/showing this?

Comment: Hint: Square both sides.

Comment: @JohnDouma  square both sides of what is to be proven?  Say we have to "Prove $-4 > 2$."  You say:  "Square both sides:"  and we get $16 > 4.$  Yes! Therefore what can we say about $-4 > 2$?

Comment: @amWhy It means to square both sides of the inequality to prove the claim. It's simple and it works. The hint was meant for this problem. I hoped that was obvious. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @JohnDouma  The point is "squaring both sides" doesn't work $a^2 < b^2 \not \implies a <, b$ as amWhy's counter examaple shows.  Now if we *ALSO* know that $a > 0; b>0$ then we can *prove* $a^2 < b^2 \implies a<b$ but we can't accept that as a god-given truth handed down from on high.

Comment: @fleablood It was a hint and it works. It is up to the poster to fill in the details. Look at the upvoted answers. They follow my hint. Is there something going on here I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

Since:

$$10+7+2\cdot\sqrt{10} \cdot \sqrt{7} > 17$$
$$(\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{7})^2 > (\sqrt{17})^2$$

and since both sides are positive:

$$\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{7} > \sqrt{17}$$

Comment: @T.Bongers I have edited.

Answer (score 3):

You can begin by squaring:

$$(\sqrt{10}+\sqrt7)^2=10+2\sqrt{10}\cdot\sqrt7+7=17+2\sqrt{70}$$ and now just observe that the square root of any positive number is poitive itself...

Answer (score 3):

First notice $0 < a < b$ then $a^2 = a*a < a*b < b*b < b^2$ and if $0 < a, 0 < b$ but $a \ge b$ then $a^2 = a*a \ge a*b \ge b*b \ge b^2$ so

Lemma: for $a >0; b> 0$ then $a < b \iff a^2 < b^2$.

So ... square both sides.  $(\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{7})^2 = \sqrt{10}^2 + 2\sqrt{10}\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{7}^2 = 10 + 2\sqrt{10}\sqrt{7} +7 =17 + 2\sqrt{10}\sqrt{7} > 17 = \sqrt{17}^2$.

So $\sqrt{10} + \sqrt 7 > \sqrt{17}$.

> It is obvious

It's not obvious to me:  $3 < \sqrt{10} < 4$ and $2 < \sqrt{7} < 3$ so $5< \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{7} < 7$ and $4 < \sqrt{17} < 5$ and  .... oh, I guess it *is* obvious .... $4 < \sqrt{17} < 5 = 3 + 2 < \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{7} < 7$

> ...and can be verified with a calculator.

Calculators are magic and we aren't allowed to use magic until we have proven magic works and is trustworthy.  So unless you can tell me *why* when I press in $\sqrt {10} + \sqrt{7}$ I get $3.1622776601683793319988935444327 + 2.6457513110645905905016157536393$ and when I press in $\sqrt 7 =4.1231056256176605498214098559741$, I won't trust it and won't let you cite that as a proof.

However if you *can* tell my why the calculators do that I can accept it as a proof.

I mean.... if we were allowed to say "My calculator told me so" we ought to be able to say "A really smart grown-up told me so" and ... well, there's no point in going to school at all then.

Comment: @fleadblood What about that [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2973638/505767)?

Comment: @fleadblood Do you think my answer is identical to your one? Please let me know, in case sorry for that it was unintentional and I'll delete.

Answer (score 1):

By [**AM-GM inequality**](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality)

$$\frac{\sqrt{10}+\sqrt 7}{2}\ge \sqrt{\sqrt{70}}\iff \sqrt{10}+\sqrt 7\ge 2\sqrt{\sqrt{70}}$$

and

$$2\sqrt{\sqrt{70}}=2\sqrt[4]{70}>2\sqrt[4]{64}= 2\sqrt 8=\sqrt{32}>\sqrt{17}$$

Comment: Your $\iff$ should probably be an $\implies$. (It is technically valid by virtue of the fact that both statements are true, but pedagogically, it makes more sense to put $\implies$.)

Comment: @TheoBendit I understand your point, I think I'll let the $\iff$ but separating the second part. Let me know if it is clear. Thanks

Comment: My point was about the $\iff$ used in the first place. Is there a simple way to conclude, from $\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{7} \ge 2\sqrt[4]{64}$, that $\frac{\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{7}}{2} \ge \sqrt{\sqrt{70}}$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Ops yes you are right! I've cancel out a step and now it is not clear I fix that.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative

$$\sqrt{10}+\sqrt 7>\sqrt{9}+\sqrt 4=3+2=5=\sqrt{25}>\sqrt{17}$$

Comment: Alternatively, $\sqrt{10}+\sqrt7\gt\sqrt5+\sqrt5=\sqrt{20}\gt\sqrt{17}$.

Comment: @BarryCipra That's also very nice!

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a concave function and $(17,0)\succ(10,7)$.

Thus, by Karamata 
$$\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{7}>\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{0}=\sqrt{17}.$$